# Limiting HTTP methods in Apache2

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, apache-2.2

I have a default Apache installation on Ubuntu 10.04.

I use the following *Nmap* scan to determine the available Apache methods:

```
nmap -p80 --script=http-methods 192.168.1.66
```

The result is:

```
http-methods: GET HEAD POST OPTIONS
```

I'm trying to eliminate the HEAD method. So in `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` I added the following:

```
<Directory "/var/www/*">
<LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
...
</Directory>
```

I then restarted the web server. However the nmap scan still prints the same results.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: I think Get and Head must be treated similarly, as Head is essentially a Get with no content returned (To check for updates).   so, I think there is some dependency between the two - that must be accounted for in configuration.

Comment: Why do you want to remove HEAD?  What benefit do you think you will gain from this?

Comment: I don't use it, so I want to disable it.

Comment: @brahims - *you* might not use it, but your browser uses it all the time. The only time you should disable it is if you have 100% control over every client application that is going to access it (for example, it's a web service that's used exclusively by your own software), but there's no security risk in `head`, so it's a bit of a misnomer anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `<Limit>` explicitly states:

```
If GET is used it will also restrict HEAD requests
```

This very strongly implies that for the purposes of `<Limit>` and `<LimitExcept>` that `GET` and `HEAD` are treated the same.  Restrictions applied to `GET` will apply to `HEAD`, and therefore if `GET` is unrestricted so `HEAD` will also be unrestricted.

Further, the `HTTP/1.1` `RFC 2616` explicitly states (section 9.4):

```
The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return
a message-body in the response.
```

Further clarifying the direct relationship between `GET` and `HEAD`.

The final piece of information to clarify this, also from `RFC 2616`, (section 5.1.1):

```
The methods GET and HEAD MUST be supported by all general-purpose servers.
```

This information all together tends to strongly imply that what you wish to accomplish will not be possible by configuration changes alone.

Comment: OK. I've tried with <LimitExcept GET HEAD> and still same nmap output :) Do you think it is possible to configure any of these 4 methods (GET HEAD POST OPTIONS) by configuration changes?

Comment: Try moving your `<Limit>` directive out of the `<Directory>` specification and into your `<VirtualHost *:80>` definition instead...

Comment: I've tried that as well.. I guess I'm just out of luck :/ Thanks for the answers anyway Mike